# "Serialize" VHDL record

Tags: serialization, record, vhdl

Suppose I have the following type definition which relies on constants to indicate vector length of the record members:

```
type point_t is record
    x: std_logic_vector(X_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    y: std_logic_vector(Y_WIDTH-1 downto 0); 
end record;
```

I would like to convert these kind of records into `std_logic_vector`s to put them into, say, a FIFO. Currently I am using the following code:

```
PROCEDURE encodepoint(signal pnt: in point_t;
                      signal d: out std_logic_vector(POINT_ENC_WIDTH-1 downto 0)) is
    variable top: integer := 0;
begin
    top := X_WIDTH-1;
    d(top downto 0) <= pnt.x;

    top := top + Y_WIDTH;
    d(top downto top-X_WIDTH+1) <= sl.y;

    d(d'left downto top+1) <= (others => '0');
end;
```

This code is suboptimal in many ways. For example it requires me to always correctly set POINT_ENC_WIDTH to a value that is big enough to allow `d` to hold the whole serialized record. It relies on the programmer to do very mechanical work. For example for every member of the record, say `x`, `X_WIDTH` appears *twice* in the code, once in direct connection with `x` and once in connection with the next member, `y`. This get tedious quickly. If I change the definition of the record by adding additional fields, I have to update both the serializing and the (very similar) deserializing code, and I may just forget this. When I remove fields, at least the compiler complains.

Thus this leads me to my question: Is there a simple, automated or at least quasi-automated way to convert VHDL records into `std_logic_vector`s without having to resort to manually written serializing/unserializing code? It is not important for me to know the specific encoding, as I am using the records internally and the final output format is clearly specified and will be implemented manually.

Answer (score 6):

Can't you just write this:

```
d <= pnt.x & pnt.y;
```

Comment: Oh, good point, thanks! Sometimes I wonder how much I am able to overlook! Is the inverse operation also writable in a similarly concise way?

Comment: I guess you need two assignments and attributes to "unpack" the record. Try something like: pnt.x <= d(pnt.x'length-1 downto 0);

Answer (score 3):

While there is currently no official automated way of converting records to vectors (and vice-versa), it is a very common requirement. You have 2 options:

- Define your own to_vector and from_vector functions for every record type (*tedious*)
- Autogenerate packages containing above type conversions (*difficult / error prone*)

Tedious and repetitive tasks that motivate you to write a script to generate code are an indication of a deficiency in the language itself. You can change this by taking an **active role** in the IEEE working-group and *influence* the [next version of the VHDL standard](http://www.eda.org/twiki/bin/view.cgi/P1076/CollectedRequirements).

Comment: We can influence the next version of VHDL but by the time it becomes available in all tools, we will be close to retirement.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from discussion [here](http://objectmix.com/vhdl/190447-converting-records-std_logic_vector.html)

One reasonable way to do this, with large records is to define the ranges ahead of time like this:

```
type t_SPI_DATA_PORT is record
  Data_Size_Minus1: std_ulogic_vector(31 downto 28);
  Done: std_ulogic_vector(27 downto 27);
  Rx_Wait_Timeout: std_ulogic_vector(26 downto 26);
  Rx_Wait_On_Miso: std_ulogic_vector(25 downto 25);
  Sclk_Select: std_ulogic_vector(24 downto 24);
  Reserved: std_ulogic_vector(23 downto 20);
  Hold_Cs: std_ulogic_vector(19 downto 19);
  Cpha: std_ulogic_vector(18 downto 17);
  Cpol: std_ulogic_vector(16 downto 16);
  Data: std_ulogic_vector(15 downto 0);
end record;
```

Then the conversion functions look like this:

```
function To_Std_ULogic_Vector(L : t_SPI_DATA_PORT) return
  std_ulogic_vector is
    variable RetVal: std_ulogic_vector(31 downto 0);
  begin

    RetVal := (others => '0');
    RetVal(L.Data_Size_Minus1'range) := L.Data_Size_Minus1;
    RetVal(L.Done'range) := L.Done;
    RetVal(L.Rx_Wait_Timeout'range) := L.Rx_Wait_Timeout;
    RetVal(L.Sclk_Select'range) := L.Sclk_Select;
    RetVal(L.Reserved'range) := L.Reserved;
    RetVal(L.Rx_Wait_On_Miso'range) := L.Rx_Wait_On_Miso;
    RetVal(L.Hold_Cs'range) := L.Hold_Cs;
    RetVal(L.Cpha'range) := L.Cpha;
    RetVal(L.Cpol'range) := L.Cpol;
    RetVal(L.Data'range) := L.Data;

    return(RetVal);
end To_Std_ULogic_Vector;

function From_Std_ULogic_Vector(L : std_ulogic_vector) return
  t_SPI_DATA_PORT is
    variable RetVal: t_SPI_DATA_PORT;
    variable Lx: std_ulogic_vector(L'length - 1 downto 0);
  begin
    Lx := L;    
    RetVal.Data_Size_Minus1 := Lx(RetVal.Data_Size_Minus1'range);
    RetVal.Done := Lx(RetVal.Done'range);
    RetVal.Rx_Wait_Timeout := Lx(RetVal.Rx_Wait_Timeout'range);
    RetVal.Sclk_Select := Lx(RetVal.Sclk_Select'range);
    RetVal.Reserved := Lx(RetVal.Reserved'range);
    RetVal.Rx_Wait_On_Miso := Lx(RetVal.Rx_Wait_On_Miso'range);
    RetVal.Hold_Cs := Lx(RetVal.Hold_Cs'range);
    RetVal.Cpha := Lx(RetVal.Cpha'range);
    RetVal.Cpol := Lx(RetVal.Cpol'range);
    RetVal.Data := Lx(RetVal.Data'range);

    return(RetVal);
end From_Std_ULogic_Vector;
```

Answer (score 2):

I typically define conversion functions in a package along with the record.

In your case, something like:

```
function point2slv (pnt : point_t) return std_logic_vector is
    variable slv : std_logic_vector(X_WIDTH + Y_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
begin
    slv :=  pnt.x & pnt.y;
    return slv;
end;

function slv2point (slv : std_logic_vector) return point_t is
    variable pnt : point_t;
begin
    pnt.x     := slv(X_WIDTH + Y_WIDTH - 1 downto Y_WIDTH);
    pnt.y     := slv(Y_WIDTH - 1 downto  0);
    return pnt;
end;
```

NOTE:
Depending on what you're trying to do, you may wish to use pre-defined sizes on one side or the other, and conversion functions to pad/clip to natural lengths (ie: perhaps fit the X and Y values into 16 or 32 bit values).  The unsigned type and resize function work well for this:

```
slv(31 downto 16):=  std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(pnt.x,16)));
slv(15 downto  0):=  std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(pnt.7,16)));
```

Comment: Hum, this is exactly the situation I have now. I try to keep the encoding/decoding functions very close to the type definitions. Your encoding/decoding code is written a little differently, with explicit indices, though the implications are the same. The more members you have in your record, the longer your lines get. For records with, say, 10 members, this becomes unwieldy. If you add or delete members, you have to update your code and be very wary that you do so correctly.

Comment: For large records with longer members, I typically explicitly define the bit regions instead of concatenating the SLVs, ie:
slv(31 downto 16) := pnt.x;
slv(15 downto  0) := pnt.y;
This is where using the resize functions can come in very handy, if the length of X and Y are not fixed:
slv(31 downto 16) := std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(pnt.x,16));

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared a script which automatically generates the `VHDL` package for conversions between the user defined record type and the s`td_logic_vector` type.

The sources of this script are published as `PUBLIC DOMAIN` in the `alt.sources` group.
You can see http://groups.google.com/group/alt.sources/browse_frm/thread/53ea61208013e9d1 or look for topic "Script to generate `VHDL` package for conversion between the record type and `std_logic_vector`"
If you want to unpack the archive from the Google archive, remember to select "`show original`" option. Otherwise the indendation of the `Python` source will be damaged.

Answer (score 0):

I did another try at record serialization. I believe my method is a bit more robust. You still need to create function for every record type but you do not need to mention ranges.

Lets say you need to serialize type_a using my package:

```
type type_a is record
  a : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
  b : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  c : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  d : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
end record type_a;

constant type_a_width : integer := 64;
```

Define two functions like this:

```
use work.SERIALIZE_PKG.all;

function serialize (
     input : type_a)
  return std_logic_vector is
  variable ser : serializer_t(type_a_width-1 downto 0);
  variable r   : std_logic_vector(type_a_width-1 downto 0);
begin  -- function serialize_detectorCacheLine_t
  serialize_init(ser);
  serialize(ser, input.a);
  serialize(ser, input.b);
  serialize(ser, input.c);
  serialize(ser, input.d);
  r := serialize_get(ser);
  return r;
end function serialize;


function deserialize (
     input : std_logic_vector)
  return type_a is
  variable ser : serializer_t(type_a_width-1 downto 0);
  variable r   : type_a;
begin  -- function serialize_detectorCacheLine_t
  ser := serialize_set(input);
  deserialize(ser, r.a);
  deserialize(ser, r.b);
  deserialize(ser, r.c);
  deserialize(ser, r.d);
  return r;
end function deserialize;
```

And then you can use it in code like this:

```
signal type_a_ser       : std_logic_vector(type_a_width-1 downto 0)       := (others => '0');
signal type_a_in        : type_a;
signal type_a_out       : type_a;
....
type_a_ser       <= serialize(type_a_in);
type_a_out       <= deserialize(type_a_ser);
```

I posted my code and example of more complex types (nested records etc) at: https://github.com/gitmodimo/vhdl-serialize